# AWS access keys (for CLI authentication, etc..) for users from a SAML identity provider, or AD connector?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-directory-services

I've been looking in to getting the AWS (web) console hooked up to an AD or ADFS setup for managing users. It was reasonable easy to get working with a SAML Identity Provider in IAM and some existing ADFS infrastructure.

The problem is that users that authenticate that way, as opposed to normal AWS user accounts, don't have any way to have associated access keys so far as I can tell. Access keys are a key concept for authenticating stuff such as the AWS CLI, which needs to be tied to individual user accounts.

What are the workarounds to allow a user authenticated via a SAML identity provider to still be able to easily use the aws CLI? The only thing I've come up with to far is some hacky crap that would proxy the `aws` cli command, request temporary 1-hour credentials from the aws STS service, put them in the aws credentials file, and forward the command to the normal AWS cli. But, that makes me want to throw up a little bit; plus, I have no idea if it would work if a command took over an hour to complete (large s3 uploads, etc..)

Suggestions? I would try the official Directory Service AD connector, but my understanding is users still just assume IAM roles and would ultimately have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Versent/saml2aws was created to address this, and has a vibrant open source community behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with [aws-adfs](https://github.com/venth/aws-adfs) for AWS CLI via ADFS

The repo owner is currently adding support for DUO MFA as well. 
It works by authenticating the user to the same page you'd use for console access then scraping the roles available. You choose a role and then aws-adfs sets the default user to the credential set needed for sts access.

After the default user is set you can cli like normal: `aws s3 ls`

https://github.com/venth/aws-adfs

Comment: aws-adfs has been updated to handle DUO push requests.